# How to add custom information on product Grid/List view page?

Tags: magento2, custom, grid-layout

I want to add a description on `product Grid/List view` page as the picture shows **(The "Order Online" and "Delivery Available" part)**. Is there any way I can achieve this? Or any extension can help me with this? I am using Magento2.3. [image]

Comment: Are you using a custom theme ?

Comment: I am now using the default Magento luma theme.

Comment: do you have access to code (files) ?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I haven't done any work with the code itself.  Do I need to modify the code?

Comment: Yes, You need to edit files! It may also require some CSS adjustment

Comment: Is there any way to do it through backend or using an extension?

Comment: @Rebecca please any code you have added to category page so share this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is static / same text for all products then you can just add this text in your theme's category listing page

OR

Best way is you create 2 product attributes ( text field ideally ) and on set option "Display on Listing Page " ( While creating attribute ).

And change your

> app/design/frontend/Company/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

file call these attributes like. Supposed your attributes codes are `order_online` and `delivery_available` then your template code would be :

```
echo $product->getOrderOnline();
echo $product->getDelieryAvailable();
```

Add above lines where you want to show on listing page ( may be under `actions-primary` div ). it will get you text / attribute which you want, Also you can set condition if **!empty** so it will only show this text where it is provided.